# Use of subjective or objective case

Tags: word-choice, pronouns, personal-pronouns

It is not good for you and (I/me) to be seen together.

What is proper grammar: I or me?

Answer (score 2):

The way I identify whether my pronouns should be subject or object pronouns is to ask, "Are they subjects or objects in the phrase/sentence?" I know that sounds trite but I have to remind myself and my students that "Objects are objects, and subjects are subjects."

So when I see "for you and (I/me)," I first notice that we have "for" as a preposition. It is called that because it is in the (pre)position of a prepositional phrase. That lets the cat out of the bag because prepositional phrases contain the "object(s) of the preposition." Since objects are objects, I need to use the object pronoun..."me".

Comment: You have the right answer, but for the wrong reason. "For" is not a preposition here, but a subordinator introducing the non-finite clause "for you and (I/me) to be seen together". Since the pronouns "you and I/me" are subject of a non-finite clause, it should be the accusative "me". Compare also "For **him** to lose his temper like that is highly unusual".  Note that non-finite clauses take accusative subjects, not nominative ones.

Comment: I'm curious, @BillJ.  How do you explain the ease with which we can separate the constituents involved?  "For you and me, it's not good to be seen together."  "To be seen together is not good for you and me."

Comment: Clauses with a  subordinate clause subject generally submit to subject extrapostion.The OP's example with "it" as subject is the extraposed version of the basic non-extraposed "To be seen together is not good for you and me".

Comment: @BillJ I want you to know that I am very interested in your comment and I am now tracking some of the differences between "traditional grammar" and "modern grammar" that take into account linguistic considerations. What has been frustrating is that the terms are not consistent across the disciplines so it is creating some ambiguity, e.g., the term "clause" is used very differently between the old and new grammar. Your comment on non-finite clauses is the same as I read in Professor Lawler's notes (posted by tchrist). I'm not yet convinced that "for" is not being used as a preposition.

Comment: @BillJ BTW, are "subordinators" the same as subordinating conjunctions? Thanks

Comment: Re your first comment: the history goes back to the preposition "for" (we see a strong similarity in meaning between _I longed for your return_ and _I longed for you to return_). Today, we need to look at the evidence. One factor is that clauses with "for" as subordinator can occur as subject, or extraposed subject as in your example. But PP's don't appear as subject in extraposed position at all and appear as subject only under highly restrictive conditions. This rules out "for" as being a preposition in examples like yours.

Comment: Re your second comment: More or less; 'subordinator' is a better term, though. Incidentally, most dictionaries follow trad grammar and call the "for" that we are discussing a preposition. But there is one dictionary that is more progressive, see the last definition here: [link](https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/for)

Answer (score 1):

> It's not good for me to eat lots of chocolate.
>
> It's not good for you to drink too much beer.
>
> It's not good for you and me to be seen together.

So the things bracketed together under "it's not good for" are in the object case.

Comment: Hello @D R Ball. Welcome to the English S.E. If you could, please elaborate more on your answer and maybe list some sources?

Comment: My reasoning was kind of inductive; my reasoning was that when we say something is good or bad for us or me, the pronoun is always in the object case (because 'it is good for he' is never heard), and in the original question, the 'you and me' are both in that place. I can't list sources I'm afraid, but what I can say is that this is not one of those instances where common informal usage is 'incorrect', such as 'it was me that knocked on your door'. In other words, I don't believe I've ever heard or read 'it's bad for I/me/he' in any context. HTH